# DocuSign - Switching account groups for production account

Tags: docusignapi

Because of some mix-up with the accounts, the production account that's holding the integration key that our application is currently using isn't tied to the correct billing account.

DocuSign support informed us that we need to add this account to the correct account group and create a new integration key.

I think what I need to do is the following:

- Create a new integration key in demo environment
- Add the account that's holding the current integration key to the newly created account group with the correct billing
- Initiate the GoLive process and promote the new integration key to production, using the same account

What I need to know:

- Will adding the account to the correct account group mess up our production service integration?
- Are there any more steps that I need to take and I may not be aware of?

Comment: Hi Miljan! Welcome to Stackoverflow.com. As your question is not related to programming or code, you have less chance to get an answer here. Your question will be best answered at [Ask Different](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Know more about what questions you can ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also have the integration key that's in production moved to a different production account for management.

To initiate this, send an email to go-live at sign docusign dot com

Include integration key id (plain text), the production management account that is currently managing it and the one you want it moved to.

Note that an integration key in production can be used by any production account, by any user, in any of the DocuSign worldwide regions. The only thing special about the production **management** account is that it is the one used to change the integration key's settings.